# error: failed to push some refs to '/home/tom/test/my_repo.git'

Tags: git

I have the repository locally in the `my_repo.git` file. I cloned it using:

`git clone my_repo.git my_repo`.

I did my changes, committed and try to push using:

`git push origin master`,

but I have the following error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/tom/test/my_repo.git'
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong that I can't push to the reposiory ".git" file? Please help.

Comment: Have you configure a remote git repo ?

Comment: @ôkio origin is automatically configured if you clone a repo

Comment: How did you create the first repo.git? If it is not a bare repository, you won't be able to push to it (and will get that error).

Comment: I received such repo from my colleague. It had initial code and I added mine, but I can't push to it. Does it mean that it is not possible to push to it?

Comment: A few lines above the "failed to push" error message, it should have told you exactly which refs it failed to push, and why... Posting the entire output might be more useful.

Comment: This is the entire output. I don't know what refs failed ! Is there possible to get to know more meaningful message?